ViewPager2 FragmentStateAdapter not updating when adding/removing fragment
I am trying to add or remove a fragment from the FragmentStateAdapter but it doesn't work.
This is my init section:
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
        new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, mViewPager,
                (tab, position) -> tab.setText(categorias.get(position))
        ).attach();

My SectionsPagerAdapter class:
private class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<>();

        void addFragment(String title, Fragment fragment) {
            categorias.add(0, title);
            mFragments.add(0, fragment);
            new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, mViewPager,
                    (tab, position) -> tab.setText(categorias.get(position))
            ).attach();
            notifyItemInserted(0);
        }

        void removeFragment() {
            tabLayout.removeTabAt(0);
            categorias.remove(0);
            mFragments.remove(0);
            notifyItemRemoved(0);
        }

        public
        SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Lifecycle lifecycle) {
            super(fm, lifecycle);
            categorias = new ArrayList<>();
            if(!prefsPor.getAll().isEmpty()) {
                categorias.add(getString(R.string.fav_tab));
                mFragments.add(Favoritos.newInstance(fecha));
                favsCount = prefsPor.getAll().size();
            }
            categorias.add(getString(R.string.first_tab));
            mFragments.add(General.newInstance(fecha));
            categorias.add(getString(R.string.second_tab));
            mFragments.add(Deportes.newInstance(fecha));
            categorias.add(getString(R.string.third_tab));
            mFragments.add(Economia.newInstance(fecha));
            categorias.add(getString(R.string.fourth_tab));
            mFragments.add(Locales.newInstance(fecha));
            categorias.add(getString(R.string.fifth_tab));
            mFragments.add(Internacional.newInstance(fecha));
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return categorias.size();
        }

    }

When I call the addFragment method it throws a error saying Fragment already added. And for the removeFragment it says IndexOutOfBoundException.
For adding the fragment I do this:
mSectionsPagerAdapter.addFragment(getString(R.string.fav_tab), Favoritos.newInstance(fecha));
I am trying to add dynamically fragments from the view pager

this is because on first time your adapter list is empty and you called mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItemCount()-1 it means -> 0 - 1 = -1 , that's
why out of bound Exception .

It is not empty, I add the fragments in the constructor. Anyway what you mention is related with the setOffscreenPageLimit which doesn't have nothing to do with the expected behavoir

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I resolved by just adding this method in the Section Adapter:
@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return mFragments.get(position).hashCode();
    }

